# Value from dropdown on IconTabBar empty

Tags: odata, sapui5

change view (XML) contains IconTabBar with 3 IconTabFilters, which contain input controls (input, combobox, datePicker...). These input controls have pre-filled value from OData model. On the bottom of the view is button "Save". When I click on "Save" button, in my "onSave" function I am reading values from input controls from all IconTabFilters, but only values from the input controls on the first IconTabFilter are filled. Values from the rest of the fields are empty.

When I click on all IconTabFilters (without changing values), click "Save", then I'm getting all values correctly.

Please what I'm doing wrong? Odata model contains all required values, and also IconTabFilters contain all required values. But I can't read them from input controls before clicking on all IconTabFilters.

Answer (score 0):

The Controls on the tabs only get initiated when they have to be displayed. This is done to improve the felt performance of the UI.

Since you are already using model binding, you should take the values out of the model instead of the input fields.